# Xcode - Center button vertically within toolbar with custom height

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, storyboard, toolbar

In my storyboard I have a toolbar with two buttons in it. When the height of the toolbar is 44, everything looks good.

[image]

But when I change the height constraint of my toolbar to 60, the left button "Nächste Frage" is not centered vertically anymore. The right button works fine, please look here:

[image]

Could you please tell me how to center the left button, too?

Comment: You can add the two buttons into a view and set the view's constraint to center vertically.

Comment: You need to provide more details on how you set up the constraints for the two buttons.

Answer (score -1):

It might be 'cause you are frames, i would suggest you to use auto-layout.

Please check if this links helps you.

https://www.raywenderlich.com/160527/auto-layout-tutorial-ios-11-getting-started